# Google Maps iframe embed changing site's font color

Tags: html, css, google-maps, iframe

I think I've encountered the weirdest bug in my web development career so far.

I have a drupal 7 site (50.116.36.192/about/project-locations), that has a page with a Google Map iframe within the node content. For some reason, on this page and on the only other page with a map (Office Locations), once the Google Map loads it seems to make the font color in SOME of the mega menus lighter than they are supposed to be. If you look at the Gallery drop down on Chrome and compare it to Case Studies (while on the Project Locations page) you'll see what I mean. If you inspect the drop-down links the color is right, but it's not rendering rendering lighter than what it should be.

It only happens in Chrome & Safari, not Firefox. Has anyone seen anything like this ever?

Thanks :)

Comment: You could try not putting the map inside of a paragraph tag.

Comment: I removed it but no luck. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Ideally you would use the https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/ instead of using an iFrame.